# CASE in sub query with SELECT

Tags: sql, oracle

This is the query that I've written

```
SELECT id, name, (SELECT is_enable FROM customers WHERE id=table_one.id) AS some_tag FROM table_one;
```

The above query returns the date like this

```
    ID NAME                       SOME_TAG
     4 name 1                          0
     3 name 2                          0
     1 name 3                          1
```

I'm trying to fit in a CASE in the above query so that I get the value of SOME_TAG as "Yes" when 1 and "No" when 0 but no luck so far. Any help/leads will be appreciated! Thanks!

So far I tried this

```
select id, name, (select is_enable case when is_enable is not null then "No" else "Yes" end from customers where id=table_one.id) as some_tag from table_one;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a join instead of a sub-query... and then this is how'd the case would work.

```
SELECT 
    t.id, 
    t.name, 
    case when c.is_enabled = 1 then 'Yes' else 'No' end 
from 
    table_one t
    left join customers c on
    c.id = t.id
```

Comment: I tweaked your solution but I get this error "No": invalid identifier in Oracle SQL CLI. :(

Comment: How did you tweak it @PythonCharmer?

Comment: select a.id, a.name_dcu, case when c.enable=1 then "Yes" else "No" END from table_one a left join customers c on c.id=t.id

Comment: Why the double quotes? [Oracle Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions004.htm)

Comment: Python spoiled my habits. Pardon! Works like a charm! :) Thank you.

Comment: Ha, no worries at all mate.

Comment: But out of curiosity if I wanted to do in sub query then how should I do it ? Would be good if you include that in your answer too :)

Comment: Would be something like `SELECT 
 id, 
 name, 
 case when 
   (SELECT is_enable FROM customers WHERE id=table_one.id) = 1 
   then 'Yes'
   else 'No'
   end
FROM table_one;` but there's no real reason to do this since it's less optimal, performance wise in larger scenarios. It's also super hard to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Below code also works for your problem

```
SELECT 
  id, 
  name, 
  (CASE is_enable 
    WHEN 1 THEN 'YES'
    WHEN 0 THEN 'NO' 
  END) AS TAG
FROM ( SELECT id, name, (SELECT is_enable FROM customers WHERE id=table_one.id) AS some_tag FROM table_one );
```

Comment: This case is sub-query form of your sql query

Comment: I'll try this one out and let you know how it works.

Comment: if  your query works as shown above `SELECT id, name, (SELECT is_enable FROM customers WHERE id=table_one.id) AS some_tag FROM table_one` because 'SELECT id,   name,   (CASE is_enable WHEN 1 THEN 'YES'    WHEN 0 THEN 'NO'   END) AS TAG FROM  some table` works